# Where does MacTex or Tex Live install documentclass and packages?

Tags: packages

When I used MikTex, I wrote a custom .sty that worked with moderncv that I had placed somewhere following the instructions on the MikTex site.

I then switch to MacTex/Tex Live, but I cannot for the life of me find my custom .sty file anymore. I have google for hours, but I can't seem to find the answer my question.

I can use MacTex to compile with my custom .sty, but I don't know where it is to make modifications.

Comment: it isn't clear what your question is, if you installed a local package then you presumably know where it is? But in any case the log file of any document using that package will show the full path to that package

Comment: Oh well, I didn't remember where I had installed it. Yes, the log file was what I was looking for. I'm dumb

Comment: Note that your own packages should not go into the same three as what MacTeX comes with. There is a special place for it this command will list it for you:: `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`, remember you need to use TDS structure inside this folder (aka a .sty package may go into a `tex/latex/mypackage/` subfolder, and you'll need to run `texhash` afterwards to get the filename database updated. Also remember that on a Mac the LaTeX installation is owned by root, so you'll need to use `sudo` in front of all the commands you want to run.

Comment: Of course MacTeX doesn't install custom packages. Find your `.sty` file and copy it in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/<name>/<name>.sty` (where `<name>` stands for your package's name (and `~` for your home directory).

Comment: @daleif yes, I need to change its location. My custom package was in a MikTex folder (bc when I installed it, I was still using TexWorks with MikTex). For some reason MacTex/TexLive are also searching inside MikTex folder for packages.

Comment: @egreg: Yeah, I just didn't know that MacTex would search for packages inside MikTex folder, which according to the log file is what is happening.

Comment: Why not just get rid of miktex all together

Comment: When I started to use MacTex, I didn't know if I'd like it, so I left MikTex there in case I wanted to switch back. Then I just forgot to uninstall it. But now that I am comfortable with MacTex, I'll go ahead and install MikTex, and organize my packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the log file of any document using that package will show the full path to that package